# Помогите разобраться с bind

Tags: администрирование, bind

Ввиду того, что мой предыдущий вопрос был в корне сформулирован неправильно, прошу помощи в настройке bind.

Мои действия

1. /etc/bind/named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

2. /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "dev" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/dev.hosts";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/192.168.0.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

3. /etc/bind/dev.hosts

```
$TTL 38400
@ IN SOA garmayev.dev. garmayev.gmail.com. (
 1192648703
 10800
 3600
 604800
 38400 )
;
@ IN NS localhost.
virtual IN A 192.168.0.49
         IN  TXT "Virtual PC for server"
         IN HINFO "Debian 7.8"
www.garmayev IN CNAME garmayev
```

4. /etc/bind/192.168.0.in-addr.arpa

```
$TTL    3600
@  IN      SOA     garmayev.dev. garmayev.garmayev.dev (
                   20060204        ; Serial
                   3600            ; Refresh
                   900             ; Retry
                   3600000         ; Expire
                   3600 )          ; Minimum
@  IN      NS      localhost.
49 IN      PTR     virtual.
```

Все остальные файлы "коробочные", т.е. без изменений

сейчас при пинге garmayev.dev, пинг идет на 127.0.53.53, хотя по идее должен идти 192.168.0.49.

**Как мне его перенастроить**?

Answer (score 1):

То,что указано в `/etc/bind/dev.hosts` не является для домена приоритетом. В самом домене указан 127.0.53.53, а так и не странно,что при пинге именно `127.0.53.53` отдает Для проверки А-записи используйте команду `dig` в терминале,если у Вас `Linux`. Вот мой вывод с терминала:

```
    dig garmayev.dev A

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> garmayev.dev a
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53656
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;garmayev.dev.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
garmayev.dev.       3599    IN  A   127.0.53.53

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 20 09:51:27 EEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно, надо добавить в /etc/bind/dev.hosts соответствующую строку:

garmayev IN A 192.168.0.49